# Displaying result in console instead of web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

The project I have created, is an ASP.NET Web API which communicates with a Java Web Service through HttpClient. When I run the Java Web Service, I get the result `{"id":2,"content":"Hello, World!"}`. When I run the ASP.NET Web API, The ASP.NET Web API gets result from the Java Web Service and displays result as `"{\"id\":2,\"content\":\"Hello, World!\"}"` in a web page.

How do I display the result in console, which means I create a console application and put in these codes and I want the result to come out in a console and not web page. How do I do that? What are the codes that has to be modified? Someone please kindly do help me thank you so much.

Here are my ASP.NET Codes that I have done so far:

**ClientController.cs**

```
public class ClientController : ApiController
{
    private ServerClient serverClient = new ServerClient();

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GET()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await serverClient.content();
            return Ok(result);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var result = "Server is not running";
            return Ok(new { ErrorMessage = result });
        }
    }
}
```

**ServerClient.cs**

```
public class ServerClient
{
    private static HttpClient client;
    private static string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    static ServerClient()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public async Task<string> content()
    {
        var endpoint = string.Format("greeting");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "TestClient",
        routeTemplate: "api/testclient",
        defaults: new { actcion = "Get", controller = "Client" }
        );
```

Comment: Do you wanna self-host the web API inside the console?

Comment: I am a bit new to this.. So i'm not so sure what self-host means. But if it allows the ASP.NET Application communicate with the Java Web Service and displays the result in console, that is what i want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = serverClient.content().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Please note that using `Result` or `Wait()` in `async` programming might cause deadlock

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me. I get the result as `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]`  instead of `"{\"id\":2,\"content\":\"Hello, World!\"}"`

Comment: Updated the answers